# How to get string value from string-array in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a spinner with some string arrays and they have some values = emails, and I need to get email (value)when specific item(string-array) selected in spinner, but all I got its just a string (Name/Title in the string array), all I need its just how to get value of a string in string-array.
the code of string-array looks like that

```
<string-array name="choose_array"> 
 <item>Choose</item>
 <item value = "something@mail.com">somethingName</item>
 <item value = "something@mail.com">somethingName</item>
 </string-array>
```

I need to get the value (email) of the selected string to work with it but I dont know how.
I tried some ways to get it but all I get its just string (somethingName in code)

Comment: Your string values are on the spinner... I don't understand the question. You get the value from the spinner text, not the array... Please edit your question to include code

Comment: Don't rest your business logic on the string values in the spinner.  Instead, use the numerical index when persisting user choices, retrieving previous settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <string-array name="progress_array">
        <item>Not Done</item>
        <item>Done</item>
        <item>On Hold</item>
        <item>In Progress</item>

    </string-array>
```

and the code for spinner is

```
 spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selection);
            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.progress_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

  public boolean doTask(){
     String spinnerValue = (String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
            if(spinnerValue.equals("Done")){
                spinnerInd = 1;

            }else if(spinnerValue.equals("Not Done")){
                spinnerInd = 0;
            }else if(spinnerValue.equals("On Hold")){
                spinnerInd = 2;
            }else if(spinnerValue.equals("In Progress")){
                spinnerInd = 3;
            }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how you get the value after a spinner selection

Comment: sry prob I didnt explain correctly 
<string-array name="progress_array">
        <item value = "something">Not Done</item>
        <item value = "something">Not Done</item>
    </string-array>
there is a value like u can see here

Answer (score 0):

Strings.xml

```
<string-array name="your_array_string">  
<item>Item1</item>
<item>Item2</item>
</string-array>
```

Convert to string array `setOnItemSelectedListener` you can get the value

```
 String[] your_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array_string);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
               String selectedValue=your_array[position];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // Your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how you get the value after a spinner selection , check edited question maybe now someone could understand my question,I am not the best explainer sry.